# how to find specific number in row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

hi I need help with this code, in one row I have a number of weeks (52) and each cell has a filter. Does anyone have any idea how I can cut a long code for 52 weeks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    If TextBox1.Value = "1" Then
        Range("E2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$E$2:$X$13").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>"
    End If

    If TextBox1.Value = "2" Then
        Range("F2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("$E$2:$X$13").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: img]

Comment: Are you trying to find the correct column, based on the user's input? So if they input `4`, it selects the 4th column (in your example I think that's column h)?

Comment: yes, I want  find the correct column based on the user's inputs, something like vlookup (I'm not sure), "it selects the 4th column", I do not understand?

Comment: no it is not vlookup, sorry :)  but i just want to find the number (from textbox1 ) in row and to do filter.

Comment: `hlookup` is the horizontal equivalent to `vlookup`. However, you could select the cell like: `worksheets("...").cells(2, TextBox1.Value + 4).select`

Comment: You can then use the `TextBox1.Value` in the `Field:=TextBox1.Value` argument.

Comment: If you write your own solution please add it as an answer.

Comment: this is what I was looking for "Field:=TextBox1.Value". thank you tospig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my proposed solution, mirroring what tospig was suggesting:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim FilterColumn As Integer
    FilterColumn = Val(TextBox1.Value)
    If (FilterColumn + 4) > 26 Then
        Range(Chr(64 + Int((FilterColumn + 4) / 26)) & Chr(64 + FilterColumn + 4 - (26 * Int((FilterColumn + 4) / 26))) & "1").Select
    Else
        Range(Chr(64 + FilterColumn + 4) & "1").Select
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Range("$E$2:$BD$13").AutoFilter Field:=FilterColumn, Criteria1:="<>"
End Sub
```

Note the +4 in the range to compensate for the offset of your table. Hope this helps even if it's a little late to the party. Cheers,

EDIT: changed script as was not considering columns past Z:Z (AA:AA, AB:AB all the way to BD:BD).